# New to Emacs. When I type ", \" is automatically inserted

Tags: emacs

As the title states, I'm relatively new to Emacs.  I tried out several starter kits but went with Prelude and changed a lot of things around.

Anyway, I've been getting a good handle on everything...until this morning I was working and I typed double-quotes.  Normally Emacs would insert a second double quotes right after ("") due to the auto-completion, but I must have accidentally changed something with a keystroke and now when I type ", I get \"\".

Thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Which major-mode are you using and what is the output of `f1 k "`?

Comment: major-mode was originally Ruby, but now I'm in Web and it hasn't changed.  f1 k " gives me an explanation of how " runs the command self-insert-mode.

Comment: `self-insert-mode` or `self-insert-command`?

Comment: self-insert-command gives me: ^M

Comment: I was asking if you're sure that output of `f1 k "` was. Can you just paste the full output?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking for, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) which prelude installs by default (see the file `prelude-programming.el`. This behavior is described in detail on [smartparens wiki](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Automatic-escaping). To ensure that smartparens is causing problems you can can do <kbd>C-h k</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> this would print about the command acutally run when <kbd>"</kbd> is pressed, if the command is `sp--self-insert-command` then the following should work

Paste this `(setq sp-autoescape-string-quote nil)` to your `*scratch*` buffer, go to the closing parenthesis and do <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-e</kbd>, this will disable the behavior for current emacs session.

To disable the behavior for all future emacs session, assuming that you are using prelude, you will need to add the following to your personal config (basically some file inside `/path/to/prelude/personal/`).

```
(setq sp-autoescape-string-quote nil)
```

This will disable the auto-escaping of the string quotes, completely. If you like this behavior and do not want to disable it completely you can do what @steckerhalter suggests <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> will insert just one parenthesis.

If the above does not solve the issue then try providing following info in your question which may help us debug the issue,

1) The list minor modes active (this can be obtained by doing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd>).

2) Output of <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you, it had to do with one of the minor modes.

Comment: To disable the feature in recent versions of smartparens you should use `(setq sp-escape-quotes-after-insert nil)`

Answer (score 4):

this sounds a lot like smartparens (https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) which is included in Prelude. usually when you are inside "" then it will escape the quotes:

```
"hahah \"\" bah"
```

if you want to get a normal " inside quotes you have to use `C-q "` or disable smartparens with `M-x smartparens-mode`

Answer (score 3):

If, as you say in a comment, `"` is bound to `self-insert-command`, then when you type `"` what happens is that a (single, unescaped) `"` character is inserted.

However, I suspect you have some mode turned on that does something additional whenever a `"` char is inserted.  You mention automatic insertion of a second `"`, for example.  That kind of behavior comes from a mode such as is provided by library smart-parens or electric-pair.

And you mention Prelude.

To find out what part of your init file (`~/.emacs`) is causing the behavior you see, bisect your init file recursively (first comment-out half, to see which half is responsible, then 3/4, to see which quarter is responsible,...).  Then, if you still have a question about the responsible code, ask here, providing that info.

When you describe your problem here, it is important to be specific: what Emacs version, what mode(s), what libraries have you loaded,...  Whatever might be pertinent.  But first narrow down the problem by bisecting your init file to find the culprit.