# After I tab-complete a file path in ESS smartparens inserts escaped quotes

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I've recently started using Emacs (prelude, which comes with smartparens installed) and am trying to write some R scripts in ESS. I find that when I tab complete a file path, for example in a call to `read.csv()`, and then try to type the second `"` to advance past it, a pair of escaped quotation marks is inserted instead. So what should be `read.csv("~/foo/bar.csv")` becomes `read.csv("~/foo/bar.csv\"\"")`.

However, if I type out the file path without using tab completion, everything works just fine and typing the second `"` just advances my cursor past it.

I tried the solution from [this slightly different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661737/new-to-emacs-when-i-type-is-automatically-inserted), and now the extra set of quotation marks is not escaped, but still inserted.

It seems that smartparens is not recognizing when I've reached the end of a pair quotation marks if I use tab completion between them. Is this the case, and if so is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that this behaviour is caused by `smartparens`.
It is related to a feature which turns off active `sexp`-expressions if you type any key other than a "normal key" like a letter. See the help for the function `sp-skip-closing-pair` and maybe its source text for more details. (If you are interested.)

To avoid it, you can customize `sp-cancel-autoskip-on-backward-movement` to `nil`.

This effects more features. For an instance the `sexp` is no longer deactivated if you move backwards with the cursor key. Nevertheless, you can deactivate it by putting the cursor outside of the `sexp`.